# Using the Kalman filter to determine beta in a regression

Tags: multiple-regression

Is the Kalman filter applicable to determine beta coefficients of a multiple regression?( 1 dependent & 3 independent variables in a time series type regression analysis)

Comment: The short answer is that there *is* indeed a connection that can be drawn, particularly to the case of streaming (one sample at a time) updates to linear-regression parameter estimates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user **cardinal** pointed out in the comment below, the Kalman filter is applicable for updating  you can flip the problem around and consider updates to the present parameter vector, $\beta_n$.

We have the re-interpreted prediction/observation equations for one additional data point:

$\beta_{n+1} = \beta_n$

$y_n=\beta_n'X_n+v_n$

Begin with estimates $\beta_{\text{init}}$ and $P_{\text{init}}$ and perform updates as:

$r = y_n - \beta_{\text{prev}}'X_n$

$s = X_n' P_{\text{prev}} X_n+\sigma_n^2$

$G = P_{\text{prev}}X_n/s$

$\beta_{\text{next}}=\beta_{\text{prev}}+Gr$

$P_{\text{next}}=(1-X_n'G)P_{\text{prev}}$

$\beta_{\text{init}}$ and $P_{\text{init}}$ come from a full multiple regression on previous data. $\sigma_n^2=\text{Var}(v_n)$ is a modeling choice that lets you control how much you allow the new data point to influence your new estimates.

<s>The Kalman filter is not directly applicable as it has a different purpose. It in fact uses a given $\beta$ and other parameters to make accurate predictions about states $X_n$ given observations $y_n$.</s>

<s>While the observation formulae are equivalent in both cases, in the case of the Kalman filter, $A$,$B$,$C$,$cov(w)$ and $cov(v)$ are provided along with $y_n$ up to some time.</s>

The difference between the techniques is one of parameter estimation (multiple regression) vs state estimation (Kalman filter).

Comment: I think this answer is a bit shortsighted. If we view $\beta$ as a constant (but unknown) state and allow for time-varying (but observable) observation matrices $C_n$ (in this case, just vectors) as the predictors, it is not at all difficult to draw a quite direct connection to the multiple regression case. Indeed, if you look at the math for streaming (single-observation) updates to linear-regression estimates, the relationship to the Kalman iterative updates is immediately apparent.

Comment: That's true: I overlooked this. I'll update my answer shortly.